# How to configure Apache Kafka to centralize Application Logs?

Tags: php, ubuntu, logging, apache-kafka

I have 10 servers which are working on Ubuntu and Nginx.

There are PHP logs that are being generated.

I want to send all the Application logs from the 10 servers to a single server that can handle at least 50k requests per second.I have installed Apache Kafka and configure it as sending a simple text to another server by following [Digital Ocean's article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-14-04), but I am not able to send PHP logs to that server.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Consider logstash for this? also what errors are you having. What is the problem?

Comment: " I am not able to send PHP logs to that server." is not helpful. Do you mean you've tried and you get an error? You've not tried and you don't know how to start?

Comment: I am not able to configure any connector on the producer to read and write application logs. I have tried to install rdkafka and PHP Kafka, installed them successfully but don't know how to make them in use because of not proper guide how it will work for application logs where to install.

Comment: Here is the error;php producer.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'RdKafka\Producer' not found 
in /var/www/html/php-rdkafka/examples/producer.php:3
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/php-rdkafka/examples/producer.php on line 3

Answer (score 2):

[Filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats/filebeat) is great for this, and has a [Kafka output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/kafka-output.html) option.